# Error while building a monolithic .NET app with Docker

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a monolithic .NET application by combining the Core and Web projects of my project. I have created a Dockerfile for my project, but I'm encountering an error during the Docker container build phase.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
- src
  - Core
    - Core.csproj
  - Web
    - Web.csproj
- Dockerfile
- Main.sln
```

And here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files
COPY src/Core/Core.csproj ./src/Core/
COPY src/Web/Web.csproj ./src/Web/
COPY Main.sln ./

# Restore NuGet packages
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the rest of the source code
COPY ./src/ ./src/
# Build the application
RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore

# Stage 2: Publish the application
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish --no-restore

# Stage 3: Create the final image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

# Set the entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

While running the command docker build -t [container_name] ., I'm getting the following error:

```
  12 |
  13 |     # Copy the rest of the source code
  14 | >>> COPY ./src/ ./src/
  15 |     # Build the application
  16 |     RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref e2ee3e56-3f10-4f1c-9cef-afaa0591bd08::ygu48ioep59fye59jsavuuwhe: "/src": not found
```

Thank you in advance for your support!

I have tried modifying the relative path in the COPY command, but I couldn't resolve the issue. I would like to seek your help in understanding how to fix this error and properly create the Docker image

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: --------------------
12 | 13 | # Copy the rest of the source code 14 | >>> COPY ./src/ ./src/ 15 | # Build the application 16 | RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref e2ee3e56-3f10-4f1c-9cef-afaa0591bd08::ygu48ioep59fye59jsavuuwhe: "/src": not found. It seems a simple folder-tree related issues, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong